# (Cumulative) baseline hazard in cox models with time-dependent coefficients

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, absolute-risk

I would like to know if there is an easy way to estimate the (cumulative) baseline hazard from a cox model with time-varying coefficients over different time intervals. After creating the time splitted data with `survSplit()`, the `predict.coxph()` method with type='expected' gives expected values per row which I guess considers the effect of same subjects multiple times. Is there an easy way to obtain these estimates? Am I thinking correctly? Let's discuss it further through an example:

```
library(survival)

library(riskRegression)

data(Melanoma)

d <- survSplit(formula = Surv(time,status==1)~age+sex+epicel,
               
               data = Melanoma,
               
               cut = 1095,
               
               episode = 'tgroup',
               
               id = 'id')

fit <- coxph(Surv(tstart,time,event)~age:strata(tgroup)+sex+epicel,data=d,x=TRUE)
```

Now for example, for a patient who got censored at time=1700, if we want to estimate the baseline hazard at times 800 & 1500, the patient is in the risk set for both times but with different linear predictors (as the cut-point in time was set at time=1095). Looks like `predict.coxph()` doesn't take this into account. Am I thinking correctly? Is there an adjustment to `predict.coxph()`? Are there any other functions to do this automatically or do I need to start writing the function myself? I want to use these values to obtain absolute risk estimates of each patient. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out a way to deal with it myself. `survfit` works with time-splitted data for time-varying coefficient if newdata argument is shaped in a time-splitted data format as well. Here we shape the information of a patient with all variables at baseline to get values of cumulative baseline hazard.

```
library(tidyverse)

nd <- data.frame(tstart=c(0,1095),
                 
                 time=c(1095,max(Melanoma$time)),
                 
                 event=0,
                 
                 tgroup=1:2,
                 
                 id=1,
                 
                 age=0,
                 
                 sex='Female',
                 
                 epicel='not present')

sfit <- survfit(fit,newdata=nd,id=id)

ggplot(data=tibble('time'=sfit$time,'Cumulative baseline hazard'=sfit$cumhaz)) + 
  
  geom_line(aes(x=time,y=`Cumulative baseline hazard`),linewidth=.75) + theme_light()
```

These values along with linear predictors can then be used to shape the absolute risk estimates.
This [vignette](https://rdrr.io/cran/survival/f/inst/doc/timedep.pdf) is a comprehensive and helpful description of time-varying covariates & coefficients. The response [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534516/survival-curve-from-time-dependent-coefficients-in-the-cox-model) is also really helpful.